# How to restrict excel from taking its default time format

Tags: c#, excel

I am exporting data to excel sheet. I have a field called totalWorkingHours as string which holds the hours and minutes as "hh:mm" e.g. "119:20". However excel reads this as a timestamp and adds seconds to it: "119:20:00". I want to remove the seconds and the value should be displayed as "119:20" only.

Following code returns the Memory Stream which is then exported to excel:

```
   public static MemoryStream GetCSV(string[] fieldsToExpose, DataTable data)
   {
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

       using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < fieldsToExpose.Length; i++)
           {
               if (i != 0) { writer.Write(","); }
               writer.Write("\"");
               writer.Write(fieldsToExpose[i].Replace("\"", "\"\""));
               writer.Write("\"");
           }
           writer.Write("\n");

           foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < fieldsToExpose.Length; i++)
               {
                   if (i != 0) { writer.Write(","); }
                   writer.Write("\"");

                   if (row[fieldsToExpose[i]].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                   {
                       var Val = (DateTime)row[fieldsToExpose[i]];
                       string output = Val.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm");
                       if (Val.TimeOfDay == new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0))
                       {
                           output = Val.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                       }
                       writer.Write(output.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       writer.Write(row[fieldsToExpose[i]].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""));
                   }
                   writer.Write("\"");
               }
               writer.Write("\n");
           }
       }
       return stream;
   }
```

[image: U can see the value coming here]

[image: Here, how it looks in excel]

Comment: select the column and change its format manually. if you cant manage, create your own as hh:mm

Comment: I don't want to format it manually, my concern is if i am getting the data in string format like '11:30' I want it to stay like this and even I don't want to change  the ':' separator.

Comment: Can you tag it with the language you're using plz (looks like Java?) Also is it possible to give enough extra code and a bit of data so we can test it?

Comment: if it was vba, `range(M:M).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"` would work.

Comment: If you want to keep the value as a text string, you will need to format the cell as text **before** placing data into it.  Of course, Excel will have problems doing any kind of math functions on it that way.

Comment: I am exporting this data to excel from web application developed in MVC .NET

Comment: Excel's default number formats are largely taken as mirror copies of the individual computer's regional settings. You cannot change the default number formats without changing the regional settings of the computer it is being opened on. However, you **can** set a column(s) to a certain number/date/time format in a template (e.g. **xlst** filetype) and create your worksheets based on the template.

Comment: Can you show the code where this is exported to Excel, or is it opened directly from the Excel app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the good solution for this would be that you add one space before your string e.g **' 110:20'**, this will work and excel would read it in string format and will not convert it to date format. hope you get the solution